# How do I send String to JTextField from helper class?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jtextfield

For example in the following code i want to change the JTextField to show whether the port im scanning is open or not but i dont know how to go about doing this. Maybe i need some helper methods?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
  console.setText("Starting check\n" +
    "Start = "+stopServTf.getText()+
    "\nStop ="+stopServTf.getText()+
    "\nPort Start ="+startPortTf.getText()+
    "\nPort Stop ="+stopPortTf.getText());
  PortScanner p= new PortScanner(Integer.parseInt(startPortTf.getText()),
    Integer.parseInt(stopPortTf.getText()),startServTf.getText());
}
```

and the other method/constructor

```
public   PortScanner(int portStart, int portStop ,String ip) {
  for (int i = portStart; i <= portStop; i++) {
    try {
      Socket ServerSok = new Socket(ip, i);
      setString(i);
      //System.out.println("Port in use: " + i);
      ServerSok.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    setStrinN(i);
    System.out.println("Port not in use: " + i);
  }
}

public static String setString(int i) {
  return "Port in use: " +i;
}

public static String setStrinN(int i){
  return "Port not in use: "+i;
}
```

So that I want to send to `console.setText();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `setString(i);`, that function returns a string that you discard (i.e. do not store anywhere).  You either need to store the string and retrieve it later, ot if you want to call `console.setText()` with that returned string, you need to pass `console` to the `PortScanner` constructor:

```
public PortScanner(int portStart, int portStop, String ip, JTextArea console)
```

and change the call to `setString(i);` to

```
console.setText(setString(i));
```

Furthermore (as the `PortScanner` constructor has changed), call

```
 PortScanner p= new PortScanner(Integer.parseInt(startPortTf.getText()),
   Integer.parseInt(stopPortTf.getText()),startServTf.getText());
```

in `actionPerformed()`

Comment: @Attila right setText() is declared as thread safe,but I saw here tons questions where this code line don't work without wrapping into invokeLater(),

Comment: I agree with mKorbel and have experienced problems when calling this method off of the EDT.

Answer (score 4):

Suggestions:

- Be sure to do your port scanning in a background thread with respect to the Swing GUI, such as one provided by a SwingWorker.
- When updating any Swing components, be sure to do this on the Swing event thread, the EDT. Again, a SwingWorker will help as it has facilities to automate this (publish/process).
- Give your GUI class a public method that would allow outside classes to update its textfield, such as `public void consoleSetText(String text)`
- Pass a reference to the GUI class into the helper class, so that the helper class can call the above mentioned method. It would of course call the method on the Swing event thread, using the SwingWorker `process(...)` method.

**Edit 1**
this is an example of what I am suggestion:

```
class PortScannerGui {
   private JTextField startPortTf;
   private JTextField stopPortTf;
   private JTextField console;
   private JTextField stopServTf;
   private JTextField startServTf;

   // ... lots of code mising

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      console.setText("Starting check\n" + "Start = " + stopServTf.getText()
            + "\nStop =" + stopServTf.getText() + "\nPort Start ="
            + startPortTf.getText() + "\nPort Stop =" + stopPortTf.getText());

      new SwingWorkerPortScannerWrapper(this, 
            Integer.parseInt(startPortTf.getText()), 
            Integer.parseInt(stopPortTf.getText()),
            startServTf.getText()).execute();
   }

   public void setConsoleText(String text) {
      console.setText(text);
   }
}

class SwingWorkerPortScannerWrapper extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {
   private PortScannerGui gui;
   private PortScanner portScanner;

   public SwingWorkerPortScannerWrapper(PortScannerGui gui, int portStart,
         int portStop, String ip) {
      this.gui = gui;
      portScanner = new PortScanner(portStart, portStop, ip);
   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      portScanner.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (PortScanner.PORT_IN_USE_NUMBER.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
               publish((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
            }
         }
      });

      portScanner.scan();
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
      for (Integer chunk : chunks) {
         gui.setConsoleText("Port in use: " + chunk);
      }
   }
}

class PortScanner {
   public static final String PORT_IN_USE_NUMBER = "port in use number";
   public static final String STRIN_N = "strinN";
   private int portStart;
   private int portStop;
   private String ip;
   private int string;
   private PropertyChangeSupport propChangeSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(
         this);
   private int portInUseNumber;

   public PortScanner(int portStart, int portStop, String ip) {
      this.portStart = portStart;
      this.portStop = portStop;
      this.ip = ip;

   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      propChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void scan() {
      for (int i = portStart; i <= portStop; i++) {
         try {
            Socket ServerSok = new Socket(ip, i);

            setPortInUseNumber(i);
            // System.out.println("Port in use: " + i);

            ServerSok.close();
         } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         setStrinN(i);
         System.out.println("Port not in use: " + i);
      }
   }

   public void setStrinN(int i) {
      // TODO do something with this?
   }

   public void setPortInUseNumber(int i) {
      int oldValue = portInUseNumber;
      int newValue = i;
      portInUseNumber = i;
      propChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PORT_IN_USE_NUMBER, oldValue,
            newValue);
   }

}
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for next so i can make the gui responsive! THANKS!

Comment: where can I see an example? I'm trying to figure it out from a book.

Comment: @anna: sorry, didn't post it. It's there now.

Comment: I see, that`s what i was trying to do, but tried a different way, with doInBackground() and I didnt get it right. Will try this right away. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to be able to access your `JTextField` instance, two ways to do it:

- pass a variable to the `PortScanner` class as a local variable
- have a static reference to the frame that contains the textfield (or to the textfield itself) so that you can access it from wherever you want

First way is more correct because it keeps encapsulation, second way is more easy and simple but exposes fields to the outside also when it's not needed so seriously which is a bad design choice in a OOP environment.

Comment: No, to the static reference. Please delete that in your answer.

Comment: It's a solution indeed, ans sometimes it's the best way to solve the problem (think about a JTetArea tha must be accessed from the whole program, passing it around wouldn't make no sense.)

Comment: Needing access to a text area from the whole program just shows a lack of proper design. And swing components can only be accessed from the EDT anyway, whereas socket IO should be done out of the EDT.

Comment: This guy is creating a fairly complex multi-class GUI/socket communication program. Do you think he really should throw out the benefits of OOPs to help reduce complexity and reduce coupling for the small benefit you mention? I think he's better off going MVC all the way and not considering making static anything other than constants.

Comment: I`ve done it by passing the JTextArea to the constructor in PortScanner, thanks for your answers

Comment: I didn't tell her to place a static reference, I just pointed out that it is a way to make it work by pointing out also that it is not a good choice although a working one. I guess this is enough, or are we assuming to answer to people that are unable to read? You seem to want to answer to the OP like if he was a child. In any case I already saw some hate from you @HovercraftFullOfEels in other questions so I'm starting to think it's just personal.

Comment: No Jack, I have nothing against you. I have down-voted your answer  not you. It is giving bad advice, pure and simple.  If you don't believe me, ask JB Nizet, one smart dude. If you remove that advice, I would remove my down vote.

Comment: I don't care about the down-vote. If someone down votes someone else he'll have his reasons, like you do. I just think that when something is explained to be good or bad or whatever then it's enough, users are not monkey indeed, I personally chose many bad design decisions in situations in which I knew I could just because good/clumsy design is not always the best choice. Otherwise most of programming creativity just gets trashed. Using tools in a different way it's just your own responsibility, otherwise noone would ever program in C since everything can unreadable/bad-designed or whatever.

Comment: It's fine for you or me to use short-cuts, but I don't think that we should be recommending bad advice short-cuts here to folks who may not know any better.

Comment: Indeed I didn't recommend it, I just said it's is possible and that it would work, and also explained why it is bad. The point is: should we prevent people from doing what they want on their own source code by omitting things or by explaining things pointing out why to avoid them? I want him to do be able to choose a bad design if he really is intended to do it, but by knowing that it's a bad design choice.

Comment: @Jack: OK, I'll buy that as long as he/she knows that it isn't recommended. Thanks for the clarification. 1+